# ruby .each to compare with index before

Tags: ruby

I'm having trouble understanding the benefits of using of methods vs normal looping in Ruby at times.  Methods seem much less flexible to me.  For ex. the .each vs a while loop.

For ex. comparing with previous index

```
i = 0
while i < array.length
    if array[i] > array[i+1]
        return true
    end
    i += 1
end
```

How would I do this with a .each? When using an array.each it seems like I only have access to the array[i] at that index.

Are methods such as .select .all? .map just shortcuts? For the problems I am working on I can solve them all with while loops (albeit with more code) however the solutions use multiple methods.  It seems easier to solve with normal looping then figuring out which specific method to use each time... is this just something I need to learn and get used to?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the purpose of that loop?  What is the code trying to accomplish?  Unless you specify the purpose, one may not be able to tell you equivalent code that does not rely on loops

Comment: Is `array` being modified from a different thread? If not, your loop is an endless loop. It is not clear what you are trying to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How would I do this with a .each?

You can use `each_with_index`.

```
array.each_with_index do |value, i|
    if value > array[i+1]
        return true
    end
end
```

But there is a "shortcut method" that you refer to that will do this pairing off for you. See [`each_cons`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_cons). Here is an example this is slightly adjusted from your question so you can see it working.

```
irb(main):023:0> array = [5,4,3,2,1]
# => [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
irb(main):024:0> array.each_cons(2) { |pair| puts "true" if pair[0] > pair[1] }
true
true
true
true
# => nil
```

> It seems easier to solve with normal looping then figuring out which specific method to use each time... is this just something I need to learn and get used to?

Yes it is something you have to get used to. It's part of the "magic" of Ruby that people often refer to. Ruby will do a lot of work for you in very little code but the learning curve is a little steeper. Once you start firing on cylinders you will be blazing fast though.

Comment: The OP has changed the question. Now, your code does what the OP's code does.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code snippet (which I think does not have any real purpose), it seems you are trying to figure out whether the given array has any element which is larger than an element that follows it.

Using idiomatic Ruby, below is one of many possible ways to do it:

```
array.each_cons(2).any? { |f,s| f > s}
```

<sub>*PS: If you lurk around in the Ruby section of StackOverflow for long enough, you will get used to doing things Ruby Way.*</sub>

Comment: I like your code. Doesn't sound confusing calling Ruby Way what is actually just functional style programming?

Comment: Well there is a reason people say "Programmers love Ruby" - it's very expressive and flexible.  Whether "Ruby Way" is correct expression or not, but there is certain flair to Ruby which makes it fun

Comment: Ruby API documentation will tell  you what are various methods, but application of them for practical usage will come with continued usage.  I learned most of my Ruby trying to answer on SO and by learning from others' answers